# Transforming "forgive me for we forgive our enemies" into a simple sentence

Tags: grammar

The way I understand it, the sentence `'forgive me for we forgive our enemies'` has a coordinating conjunction i.e. *for* and hence it could be considered a 'compound sentence' having two independent clauses.

If that is correct, is there a way to transform this sentence into a 'simple sentence' with only one clause without affecting its meaning?

(I couldn't find a related tag for the post)

**Edit 1:** This question is related to what my grammar book calls 'synthesis of sentences'. I am not assuming that anyone here does not understand what 'synthesis of sentences' refers to, but just to clarify what **I** understand about it, it refers to the transformation of simple, compound and complex sentences.

Example: `As he saw the police, he ran away` – a complex sentence with two clauses as there are two finite verbs, `saw` and `ran`. This sentence could be rewritten (transformed) as: `Seeing the police, he ran away` which is a simple sentence with one clause and one finite verb or with one subject and one predicate since `seeing`, which is a present participle, functions as a non-finite verb.

That's just what I know about. I felt that some sentences cannot be transformed and was wondering if `forgive me for we forgive our enemies` or even `the thief crept as a jackal does` was one such sentence.

Comment: It's not a *compound* sentence, but a *complex* one; *for* is not a coordinating conjunction but a subordinating conjunction. This is not what traditional grammar teaches; but the *for* clause acts as a sentential adjunct, just like a *because* clause.

Comment: I see your point. But where I live, English is a foreign language and we learn it largely by referring to grammar books. I am not saying that my grammar books are the only valid reference, so I do try to verify that information online. Here, [this website](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/conjunctions-coordinating.htm) listed `for` among the seven coordinating conjunctions. I too feel that `for`, that can be substituted with _because_, _since_, _as_, etc, is more like a subordinating conjunction.

Comment: Where did you encounter this sentence?  It is highly reminiscent of "forgive us our sins, as we forgive those who sin against us" from the Lord's Prayer, but I have never heard it in this form.

Answer (score 3):

OP's usage was common enough a century or two ago, but today you'd normally only find ***for*** being used to mean ***because*** in deliberately archaic/poetic contexts...

> [*Lord, help me **for** I am poor and alone.*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5_nckhNcJXoC&pg=PA10&dq=%22help%20me%20for%20I%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6RQqU6XIOaGj0QWntIHoAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22help%20me%20for%20I%22&f=false)

My guess is it's impossible to recast OP's exact words into a "simple" sentence (whatever that means), because semantically there are effectively two separate elements...

> *We forgive our enemies*
>    *[So/Therefore, please/you should] forgive me*

You can only recast it into more modern English - *"We forgive our enemies, **so** you should forgive me"*.

---

As has been pointed out, perhaps what OP actually means is *"Forgive me **in the same way that** we forgive our enemies"*. Because the sentiment itself has "dated" religious overtones of The Lord's Prayer *("Forgive us our trespasses **as** we forgive those that trespass against us")*, it's not a good example to "modernise". But in general we tend to use ***like*** in such constructions today...

> *"I just wish you could love me **like** I love you"* (where ***as*** would be somewhat dated/poetic today).

---

It's also worth pointing out that ***as*** = because could be used in my first example, but my feeling is that in general we tend to avoid using ***as*** with *either* of those senses today. Or if we do, we tend to use other "devices" to make the meaning clearer...

> 1: *"**As** you said you wouldn't be home until late, I only cooked tea for myself"*
>    2: *"I only cooked tea for myself **as** you said you wouldn't be home until late"*

Putting ***as*** at the start in #1 makes it "stand out" more, so it's easier to parse/interpret (but probably most speakers would use ***since*** or ***because*** anyway).

> 3: *"I only cooked tea for myself, **just as** I usually do on Tuesday nights when you work late"*

Including ***just*** also helps the usage stand out - again, making it easier to parse (but many speakers today would use ***like*** there, even though others may consider such usage "slangy").

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. But my question is not about the archaic usage of _for_ or how it can be substituted with other conjunctions. Please look at the edit I have made to add more information.

Comment: @Elzee: Well, if I didn't understand what you were asking before, I certainly don't understand any better following your edit. Perhaps [this link](http://eslbee.com/sentences.htm) will help you, if you want to know more about *simple, complex, compound* sentences. But I can't see why you would want to "transform" a complex sentence into a simple one, or what kind of "rules" might enable you to do this.

Comment: The need to transform a complex sentence into a simple sentence is merely academic in this context. I think the idea is to enable the learner to see different possibilities of expressing the same idea. Like I said in the edit, it's a book intended to help one learn English as a foreign language. I simply picked a sentence from the 'exercises' section, unsure if it was possible to transform every complex sentence into a simple one. But it's OK if you still don't see what I am getting at because the way you know English as a language can be very different from the way I am learning it.

Comment: @Elzee: All I can say is if that book gave *"As he saw the police, he ran away"* as an example "complex" sentence capable of being transformed into a simple one, you might want to consider getting a different textbook. A learner might have trouble figuring out why that "transformation" (presumably, presented as a useful "technique/rule") wouldn't work with, say, [As I got dressed the phone rang](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22as+I+got+dressed+the+phone+rang%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

Comment: Yes, I agree. The transformation doesn't seem to work with `As I got dressed, the phone rang` and we can possibly come up with many such instances where rephrasing a complex sentence into a simple one is either not possible or doing so results in distorted meaning. That's what I was waiting to hear and although you haven't said it explicitly, you have surely implied it.

Comment: Elzee: The problem with your "police" example turns on the fact that "as" can mean either "because" or "while". I'm not really up on this kind of "grammar terminology" (I'm sure @StoneyB would know more), but if I needed to learn this to pass an exam, I'd want to know if (and ***exactly** why*) *"Seeing the police, he ran away"* is a "simple sentence". It looks to me more like a "compound sentence" prefaced by either an implicit "coordinator" such as ***Upon***, or a "null coordinator" (if the grammarians accept such a designation).

Comment: From what I have studied at school, I can explain it thus: _"Seeing the police, he ran away"_ is a simple sentence because by definition (again, it's what I have been taught) a simple sentence is the one that has only one subject and one predicate or in other words, only one clause, and there aren't two clauses in that sentence because _seeing_ is a non-finite verb not limited by tense or person and it exists as part of one and the same predicate. But we will have two clauses if _seeing_ is changed into a finite verb like in _"As he __saw__ the police, he ran away"_. That's just what I learnt.

Comment: Elzee: Yes, I understand that simplistic perspective. All I'm saying is the presence or absence of the co-ordinator ***upon***, and the possibility of swapping what look to me like two separate "clauses", hardly seem to me to be justification for classifying your version as "simple" unless we do the same with *"He ran away upon seeing the police"*. Which looks more like a "compound" sentence. Whatever - I have little interest in this level of "micro-classification".

Answer (score 2):

This sentence is, simply put, *do this because this happens*. The 'because' can be replaced with many words, one of them being 'for', as is this example.

I don't know why you would want a simple sentence out of this because it's quite elegantly put, but I think (think) you could say **Forgive me in the same way we forgive our enemies**. This may also be seen as a conjunction, but it is far more subtle, and is correct and almost exactly the same in meaning.

Comment: Or even “Forgive me ***as*** we forgive our enemies.”

Comment: 'Forgive me _in the same way_ or _as_ we forgive our enemies' is still a complex sentence, as StoneyB has pointed out, because it still has two clauses with two finite verbs.

Comment: @Scott, [that](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19458/transforming-forgive-me-for-we-forgive-our-enemies-into-a-simple-sentence#comment35966_19459) is more reminiscent of the Lord's Prayer, by which this sentence was surely inspired, but it's different, no?  The "for" in the original question means, as @‍MMJZ says, "because"; but the "as" in your suggested substitute means, I would think, "in the same way as".

Comment: @LSpice: Well, yes, but you understand me perfectly and misunderstand me at the same time. I wasn’t answering the question; I was responding to MMJZ’s answer. Yes, “Forgive me as we forgive our enemies” means pretty much the same as “… in the same way as …”, and I was suggesting it as a less wordy, less clunky substitute for what MMJZ said.

Answer (score -1):

The answer of the above question is:
Forgive me for us forgiving our enemies.
This is a simple sentence as it has one finite verb, which is 'forgive'. The subject of the sentence, You, is implied though.
The answer 'Forgive me for forgiving our enemies' cannot be correct because the meaning of the question and the answer is not the same. Forgive me for forgiving our enemies means I am the only forgiver forgiving our common enemies. But the question states it clearly that we all forgive our enemies and I want the implied subject, most probably God, to forgive me for all of us.

Comment: No: *for* here does not introduce a complement, the act which must be forgiven, as in *Forgive me **for** interrupting you*, but an adjunct, *Forgive me, because I forgave John*.